# Proving minium and supremum of a set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

This was on an Analysis I short test I took yesterday:

$K$ is an ordered field, let $M \subset K$ and $x,y \in K$ with $|x|<|y|$ so that

$$M=\{z\cdot z :x<z\leq|y| \}$$

For which $x$ and $y$ does a *minimum* or *supremum* exist in $K$? Calculate them if they exist.

My answer:

- The minimum is $0$ for $x \in (-P)$ and for all $y$. $0 \in K$.
- The infimum is $x\cdot x$ for $x \in \{0\}\cup P$  and for all $y$. Since  $x\cdot x \notin M$ there exists no minimum.
- The supremum is $y \cdot y$ for all $x$ and $y$ and since K is a field and $y \in K$, $y\cdot y \in K$.

Is my answer correct? The way I went on proving this was dubious at best and I would like to know how it could be done properly or if there are any general tips that help prove such things.